# onActivityResult not working

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have `ExpandableListView` and on each child element a button which calls another (edit)activity.

```
public void editSet(Set set, int groupPosition, int childPosition){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, editSetActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("set", set);
    intent.putExtra("groupPosition", groupPosition);
    intent.putExtra("childPosition", childPosition);
    startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_RESPONSE);
}
```

Activity which opens on click has this method

```
public void save(View view){
        ***some code***
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, startWorkoutActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("set", newSet);
        intent.putExtra("groupPosition", groupPosition);
        intent.putExtra("childPosition", childPosition);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        Log.d("cia", "------");

        finish();
    }
```

But when this activity is closed `onActivityResult` is not called (I've put Log in it and it doesn't show up).
`AndroidManifest` doesn't have `noHistory` or `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

edit:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("log", "*************");
        if (requestCode == EDIT_RESPONSE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Set newSet = (Set)data.getSerializableExtra("set");
                int groupPos = (Integer)data.getSerializableExtra("groupPosition");
                int childPos = (Integer)data.getSerializableExtra("childPosition");
                Log.d(String.valueOf(groupPos), String.valueOf(childPos));
                ArrayList<Set> tempSet = (ArrayList<Set>)setList.get(groupPos);
                tempSet.set(childPos, newSet);
                setList.set(groupPos, tempSet);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your onActivityResult method ??

Answer (score 0):

```
public void save(View view){
    ***some code***
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("set", newSet);
    intent.putExtra("groupPosition", groupPosition);
    intent.putExtra("childPosition", childPosition);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    Log.d("cia", "------");

    finish();
```

Comment: You should add some description of how your code solves the question.